# In HAProxy, Can I switch backends on the basis of health checks?

Tags: haproxy

Consider we have two backends say backend_1 and backend_2.

I have a requirement to always move traffic to backend_1 and use backend_2 only if backend_1 servers health checks fail.

Is it possible in HAProxy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In haproxy keyword `backend` is a group of servers. So solution depends on what you need.
If you mean `backend` in general sense, as servers then [`backup`](https://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/2.4/configuration.html#5.2-backup) keyword is the answer:

```
frontend foo
  bind *:80
  default_backend bar

backend bar
  option allbackups
  server bar1 10.0.0.1:80 check
  server bar2 10.0.0.2:80 check
  server bar3 10.0.1.1:80 check backup
  server bar4 10.0.1.2:80 check backup
```

I added 4 servers to backend and option `allbackups` to make it behave similar to the next example.

If you mean `backend` in haproxy sense as group of servers then [`nbsrv`](https://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/2.4/configuration.html#7.3.2-nbsrv) will be useful:

```
frontend front
  bind *:80
  acl is_foo_alive nbsrv(foo) -m int gt 0
  use_backend foo if is_foo_alive
  use_backend bar

backend foo
  server foo1 10.0.0.1:80 check
  server foo2 10.0.0.2:80 check

backend bar
  server bar1 10.0.1.1:80 check
  server bar2 10.0.1.2:80 check
```

`nbsrc(foo)` tells us how many servers are up in backend `foo`, so if we get more than 0, then we use backend `foo`. If not, we use next rule, which is `use_backend bar`.

Those solutions are similar, but may differ depending on how backends differ (e.g. manipulation of HTTP headers, HTTP authentication, etc.) and whether you use session stickiness.